# Unexpected Scala Map type

Tags: scala, type-inference

In Scala (2.10) if I ask for a `List(1.0, 2)` then I get a `List[Double]`, as expected.

But...

if I ask for a `Map(1.0 -> 'A', 2 -> 'B')` I get a `Map[AnyVal, Char]`.  I'd like the keys to be of type `Double`.   Asking for `Map[Double, Char](1.0 -> 'A', 2 -> 'B)` gives a type mismatch on '2'.

This I find most confusing!  Is it not inconsistent?

**Aside:** `List[(Double, Char)]((1.0, 'A'), (2, 'B')).toMap` gives me a Map[Double, Char] though.

Comment: Reproducable on 2.9.2 as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look into Scala's [type hierarchy](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/128), you can see that the primitive types are not in a sub-type/super-type relationship. However, there is a mechanism called numeric widening which for example allows you to call a method that takes a `Double` argument, by passing in say an `Int`. The `Int` then is automatically "widened" to `Double`.

This is the reason that `List(1.0, 2)` gives you `List[Double]`.

But the `Map` constructor takes `Tuple[A, B]` arguments. The numeric widening doesn't apply to higher order types, so the target type inference doesn't work for you if you mix numeric types.

```
case class Test[A](tup: (A, Char)*)
Test(1.0 -> 'A', 2 -> 'B') // AnyVal
```

Moreover, the arrow operator `->` gets in your way:

```
Test[Double](2 -> 'B') // found: (Int, Char)  required: (Double, Char)
```

This is another limitation of the type inference I think. Writing a tuple `a -> b` is syntactic sugar for `(a, b)`, provided by the implicit method `any2ArrowAssoc` on [`Predef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef%24). Without this indirection, if you construct the `Tuple2` directly, it works:

```
Test[Double]((2, 'B'))
```

So the numeric widening still doesn't work, but at least you can enforce the type:

```
Map[Double, Char]((1.0, 'A'), (2, 'B'))
```

---

A final example showing numeric widening working:

```
def map[A, B](keys: A*)(values: B*) = Map((keys zip values): _*)
map(1.0, 2)('A', 'B') // Map[Double, Char]
```

Answer (score 3):

In the case of a List, without a type declaration, Scala looks at all the elements and tries to find the common type.  In your case, since Int can be converted to Double, it converts your mixed List into a List[Double] promoting your one Int.

The Map constructor takes a series of 2-tuples.  You would get the same behavior, if you just constructed a list of tuples:

```
scala> List((1, "one"), (2.0, "two.oh"))
res0: List[(AnyVal, String)] = List((1,one), (2.0,two.oh))
```

Tuple2[Int, String] cannot automatically be promoted to Tuple2[Double, String].  In this case, you'll need to help the compiler out a bit with a type declaration:

```
scala> val x: List[(Double, String)] = List((1, "one"), (2.0, "two.oh"))
x: List[(Double, String)] = List((1.0,one), (2.0,two.oh))
```

or

```
scala> val x = List[(Double, String)]((1, "one"), (2.0, "two.oh"))
x: List[(Double, String)] = List((1.0,one), (2.0,two.oh))
```

or in your case:

```
scala> val x = List[(Double, String)]((1, "one"), (2.0, "two.oh")).toMap
x: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Double,String] = Map(1.0 -> one, 2.0 -> two.oh)
```

For some reason, using the type declaration on Map doesn't work.  Not sure why:

```
scala> val x = Map[Double, String](1 -> "one", 2.0 -> "two.oh")
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
found   : (Int, String)
required: (Double, String)
   val x = Map[Double, String](1 -> "one", 2.0 -> "two.oh")
```